# is it posible to make a multiline itemize justifying the text inside

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

I am writing technical specs of a programming API. I am using itemize to highlight the method signature as it follows:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\texttt{packeteer.send(message)}] \hfill \\
     is used to send a given \texttt{message} 
     through \texttt{packeteer} object.
\end{itemize}
```

Usually, a signature can be longer than page width and it runs out of margins:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\texttt{packeteer.send(message, offset, length, port, direction, [function(error, bytes)\{ \}])}] \hfill \\
     is used to send a portion of a given 
     \texttt{message} through
     \texttt{packeteer} object.
\end{itemize}
```

Is it possible to have the text inside item multilined and those lines to be justified too?

It's something like this, but having the first line justified and a properly space between them:

```
\item[{\parbox[t]{1.0\linewidth}{\texttt{packeteer.send(message, offset, length, port, direction, \\ [function(error, bytes)\{ \}])}}}]
```

Comment: What about `\linebreak` instead of ``\\``?

Comment: what I'm looking for is to break the line, manually o automatically, for example, between "port" and "direction" arguments in the signature of the method. I'm not having `\linebreak` working inside `\item`

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the layout a bit, but something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
 \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\leftmargin+\linewidth-\labelsep}{%
     \normalfont\bfseries\raggedright #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item[\texttt{packeteer.send(message)}]
     is used to send a given \texttt{message} 
     through \texttt{packeteer} object.
   \item[\texttt{packeteer.send(message, offset, length, port, direction, [function(error, bytes)\{ \}])}] 
     is used to send a portion of a given 
     \texttt{message} through
     \texttt{packeteer} object.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It breaks line really well, but text on first line in second item is not justified. Also, I've found that space between last item line and description first line is narrower than the other spaces in document

Comment: @subterraneanhomesick I added `\raggedright` you can take it out if you like, I thought the signature looked rather odd justified, the short case is set natural width as it is the last line of a para, but then the two line case gets all stretched, but if that is what you want just remove `\raggedright`  you might get better space-after if you change `[t]` to `[b]`

Answer (score 3):

One possibility using the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\setupdes{%
  \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\leftmargin+\linewidth\relax}{\ttfamily##1}}}
\setlist[description]{labelsep=0pt,before={\setupdes}}

\begin{document}   

\begin{description}
\item[packeteer.send(message)]
     is used to send a given \texttt{message} 
     through \texttt{packeteer} object.
\item[{packeteer.send(message, offset, length, port, direction,[function(error, bytes)\{ \}])}]
     is used to send a portion of a given 
     \texttt{message} through
     \texttt{packeteer} object.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, instead of modifying `description`, you could also easily define your own structure.

Comment: It works fine, but I don't need second line indentation in item, could it be removed? Anyway, it does not justify the first line text in item

Comment: @subterraneanhomesick please see my updated answer.

Comment: It's a better approach, but it's basically what @David Carlisle showed us in his answer. The main problem is still that the first line, `packeteer.send(message, offset, length, port,`, is not justified, it doesn't end for example, where `of a given \texttt{message} through \texttt{packeteer} object.` ends.